# rest api call statement is not covered using angular jest

Tags: jestjs, angular7

Statement is not covered in the below attached image, Please forgive me if anything missed,

[image]

Also please find below my unit test case code.

```js
test('getAllEndpoints method should retrun the respone', (done: Function) => {
        spyOn(submissionService, 'getAllEndpoints').and.returnValue(of(mockMarketEnpointEmptyResponse));
        submissionService.getAllEndpoints().subscribe((response: IGetAllEndPoints) => {
            expect(response).toEqual(mockMarketEnpointEmptyResponse);
            expect(response.responseObject.endpoint).toEqual([]);
            expect(response.responseObject.market).toEqual([]);
            expect(response.responseObject).not.toBeNull();
            expect(response.responseObject).not.toBeUndefined();
            expect(response.responseObject).toBeTruthy();
            component.data.isUpdate = true;
            component.endPointList = response.responseObject.endpoint;
            component.marketList = response.responseObject.market;
            component.showErrorNotificationForFilters();
            done();
        });
    });
```

I dont know how to cover this statement using jest, Please help me on this.